# Is it possible to selectively sync lookup tables based on user location in CommCare?

Tags: commcare

I've seen [this documentation](https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/Assigning+Lookup+Table+Rows+to+a+Location) on assigning lookup tables/fixtures to specific locations in CommCare.

My question is if I assign every lookup table to a location using the above docs, can I assure that users who are assigned to different locations will only get the lookup tables assigned to their location in the location hierarchy?

Answer (score 1):

That's correct - if you assign a row in the lookup table to a location, then that row will be available for all users in that location set.

For example, lets say I assign a particular row to the location called "Gujarat".  That means that any users assigned to Gujurat *or* any of Gujurat's child locations (i.e. Surat or Navsari) will get that row.

Answer (score 1):

You can only assign *rows* of a lookup table to a location, not the table itself.  However, rows that are assigned to a location will not be sent to users not at that location or its descendants.

If a whole table is irrelevant, then I believe the user will get essentially an empty table in the restore.  If your concern is primarily sync size, then this should help.